# Какие ограничения необходимы для корректной отрисовки треугольника по трём сторонам?

Tags: javascript, геометрия

Не получается корректно отрисовать треугольник. Например: если задать линии `a`:`100`, `b`:`200`, `c`:`200` нижняя точка не по центру.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же есть проблема, что если задать такие параметры линии: `a`:`100`, `b`:`100`, `c`:`199` треугольник не влезает в холст. Как правильно его уместить в таком случае (можно с `viewBox`)?

Какие ограничения или проверки необходимо написать, чтобы правильно строился треугольник?

```js
$('.submit').on('click', () => draw());

function check(a,b,c){
  if (a >= b+c) return false;
  if (b >= a+c) return false;
  if (c >= b+a) return false;
  return true;
}

function draw(){
  const a = $('input[name="a"]').val();
  const b = $('input[name="b"]').val();
  const c = $('input[name="c"]').val();
  
  if(!check(+a,+b,+c)) {
    alert('Сторона не может быть больше суммы двух других!');
    return;
  }
  
  const xC = (b*b + a*a - c*c) / (2 * c);
  const yC = Math.sqrt(a*a - xC*xC);
  
  ac.setAttribute('x1', 0);
  ac.setAttribute('y1', 0);
  ac.setAttribute('x2', a);
  ac.setAttribute('y2', 0);
  
  ab.setAttribute('x1', 0);
  ab.setAttribute('y1', 0);
  ab.setAttribute('x2', xC);
  ab.setAttribute('y2', yC);
  
  bc.setAttribute('x1', a);
  bc.setAttribute('y1', 0);
  bc.setAttribute('x2', xC);
  bc.setAttribute('y2', yC);
  
}
```

```css
.submit{
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px grey solid;
  user-select:none;
}
.submit:active{
  background-color:lightgrey;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>a: <input value="60" type="text" name="a"></label><br>
  <label>b: <input value="60" type="text" name="b"></label><br>
  <label>c: <input value="60" type="text" name="c"></label><br>
</div>
<div class="submit">Нарисовать</div>

<svg id="svg" width="600" height="600">
  <line id="ac" x1="0" y1="100" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="red" />
  <line id="ab" x1="0" y1="100" x2="50" y2="0" stroke="red" />
  <line id="bc" x1="50" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="red" />
</svg>
```

Comment: можешь привести пример как есть и как должно быть? Сейчас не совсем понятно что именно некорректно отрисовывается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.submit').on('click', () => draw());

function check(a,b,c){
  if (a > b+c) return false;
  if (b > a+c) return false;
  if (c > b+a) return false;
  return true;
}

function draw(){
  const a = $('input[name="a"]').val();
  const b = $('input[name="b"]').val();
  const c = $('input[name="c"]').val();
  
  if(!check(+a,+b,+c)) {
    alert('Сторона не может быть больше суммы двух других!');
    return;
  }
  
  const xC = (b*b + a*a - c*c) / (2 * a);
  const yC = Math.sqrt(b*b - xC*xC);
  
  ac.setAttribute('x1', 0);
  ac.setAttribute('y1', 0);
  ac.setAttribute('x2', a);
  ac.setAttribute('y2', 0);
  
  ab.setAttribute('x1', 0);
  ab.setAttribute('y1', 0);
  ab.setAttribute('x2', xC);
  ab.setAttribute('y2', yC);
  
  bc.setAttribute('x1', a);
  bc.setAttribute('y1', 0);
  bc.setAttribute('x2', xC);
  bc.setAttribute('y2', yC);
  
}
```

```css
.submit{
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px grey solid;
  user-select:none;
}
.submit:active{
  background-color:lightgrey;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>a: <input value="60" type="text" name="a"></label><br>
  <label>b: <input value="60" type="text" name="b"></label><br>
  <label>c: <input value="60" type="text" name="c"></label><br>
</div>
<div class="submit">Нарисовать</div>

<svg id="svg" width="600" height="600">
  <line id="ac" x1="0" y1="100" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="red" />
  <line id="ab" x1="0" y1="100" x2="50" y2="0" stroke="red" />
  <line id="bc" x1="50" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="red" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Не знаю кто минусанул, но у меня пока не получилось сломать)

Comment: @doox911 Минусанул кто-то, кто не знает геометрии.